# Custom Product Attribute Not Always Available

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, model, resource-model

In some situations, custom `catalog_product` attributes that I've created aren't loaded with the rest of the product data. So take the custom attribute, `multiplier`.

I want to display the `multiplier` attribute right next to the `price` attribute in the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price` block. However, the instance of the model that I get from `$_product = $this->getProduct();` doesn't include this custom attribute.

Now I know there are some tricks to get it to load, for instance:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_product = $_product->load($_product->getId());
```

Or I can add the attribute when selecting the product

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('multiplier')
```

But I'd rather avoid this. Instead, I think I've done something wrong to cause my custom attributes to not be loaded by default along with system attributes. I'd like to correct the problem at the root, but I don't know how to do that.

**Edit:**

I have found that setting `Use in Product Listings` to `Yes` for this attribute fixes the problem. However, I'm not sure if that's a good idea. Won't some themes end up listing this with other attributes like Color and Size?

Answer (score 1):

`Use in Product Listings` to `Yes` and `Visible on Product View Page on Front-end` to `Yes` is standard Magento approach and this is the easiest and good solution. It doesn't cause of another problem on product listing.